# Android app for detecting screen content changes and simulating touch commands

Tags: android

I am looking for an app (App1) that runs in background, can detect screen content changes, and can simulate touch commands. An example use case is as follows.

Say there is an app (App2) that shows a red color rectangle. If App2 is kept open, the color of the rectangle changes to yellow after sometime. When this happens, I want App1 to detect that a color change happened, and simulate a touch on the rectangle. Assume App1 can have all necessary permissions (e.g., screen recording and accessibility permissions for simulating touches).

Is there an app that encompasses the functionality of App1?

Comment: Is there anything else that changes, like text, or just the rectangle?

Comment: Related on Android.SE: [Detecting screen content changes and simulating touch commands accordingly](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251444/44325)

Comment: Is this question about test automation? AFAIK, the testing is usually done via USB debugging, i.e. you have an app on the PC that sends commands to the Android phone. Benefit is also: the test results will be recorded by the PC and submitted to other systems (like JIRA, TFS or similar).

Comment: @Destroy666 in my current use case only the rectangle changes. Does it help if there are text changes?

Comment: Could be, depending on how accurate you want it to be. That Automate solution seems to be quite a loose condition. There are also tools like Tasker and e.g. AutoInput that could have more control.